# Does と言いますか has a different nuance from というか?

Tags: nuances, reading-comprehension

> いや…お前がモテるから　牽制と言いますか…

Upon asking his girlfriend why she doesn't hide their relationship outside, she says this

I can gather she's essentially saying "You are popular... so this way they'll be discouraged".

However what is the difference with と言いますか an the normal というか? This character doesn't normally use polite speech, let alone with her boyfriend.

Comment: I can only guess about the speech style of someone whose personality I don't know at all, but isn't it common for anyone to become more polite in their tone when saying things that are embarrassing or hard to admit? In such situations, it wouldn't be surprising if an English speaker switches from 'Yeah' to 'Y-Yes'.